# What Superbaby adventures are there?

Tags: dc, superman

When I was a child (around 30+ years back) I read a comic or two about Superbaby. I never found more stories/adventures of Superbaby.

Is there a significant number of comics about Superbaby? If there are, is there any particular era where I can find more fun stuff about Superbaby?

I saw the [Superman wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman) but couldn't find anything more.

Comment: Superbaby as in baby superman? http://www.comicvine.com/superbaby/4005-9981/

Comment: [This Superbaby](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Superbaby_(Earth-One))? There's a link there to 58 appearances of him.

Comment: http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Superbaby_(Earth-One)/Appearances

Comment: It amuses me that, when a person asks to be led to a comic book about a Superbaby, within one hour there are three completely different comics linked to the question.  Ah, the Silver Age...

Comment: The problem is figuring out right from when they were published to getting the actual issue numbers. For e.g. in http://www.comicvine.com/superbaby/4005-9981/ if I click on http://www.comicvine.com/superboy/4050-19154/object-appearances/4005-9981/ it says there were 230 comics, figuring out the 34 appearances in the 230 odd comics is going to be hard job. I would like and prefer a list, something I could print and order or ask around for specific issues.

Comment: @shirish The second link in your comment shows specific issue numbers... Do you need something more specific than that?

Comment: @GorchestopherH It seems you mean the third one http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Superbaby_(Earth-One)/Appearances But as can be seen there is no single list I can export or import via that wikia. I have to go to each image or either hover or open it in its own tab/window and then copy and paste. I'm looking if there is some sort of semi-automated of doing this other than going to each web-page separately. A big timesink if you know what I mean.

Comment: @shirish You essentially want that exact web page without images... You may be at the wrong SE. In the spirit of fun, here are the Superboy issues with Superbaby in them: 8,26,51,59,71,73,75,76,77,78,79,83,87,90,95,97,102,105,106,112,119,120,124,130,133,134,167,178,182,183,187,189,192,196

Comment: @shirish The DC-Wikia link also allows you to view everything in "list view".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this hasn't been closed. Here's an answer that is copied and pasted from the following website: http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Superbaby_(Earth-One)/Appearances

> Action Comics Vol 1 242
> Action Comics Vol 1 246
> Action Comics Vol 1 281
> Action Comics Vol 1 288
> Action Comics Vol 1 399
> Adventure Comics Vol 1 210
> Adventure Comics Vol 1 231
> Adventure Comics Vol 1 238
> Adventure Comics Vol 1 240
> Adventure Comics Vol 1 242
> Adventure Comics Vol 1 243
> Adventure Comics Vol 1 287
> Adventure Comics Vol 1 299
> Adventure Comics Vol 1 311
> Adventure Comics Vol 1 313
> Adventure Comics Vol 1 320
> Adventure Comics Vol 1 337
> Amazing World of Superman Vol 1 1
> Best of DC Vol 1 44
> Best of DC Vol 1 46
> DC Special Blue Ribbon Digest Vol 1 9
> More Fun Comics Vol 1 101
> Showcase Vol 1 9
> Showcase Presents: Superman Vol 1 1
> Superboy Vol 1 73
> Superboy Vol 1 76
> Superboy Vol 1 102
> Superboy Vol 1 120
> Superboy Vol 1 124
> Superboy Vol 1 130
> Superboy Vol 1 133
> Superboy Vol 1 182
> Superboy Vol 2 19
> Superboy and the Legion of Super-Heroes Vol 1 255
> Superman Vol 1 128
> Superman Vol 1 130
> Superman Vol 1 132
> Superman Vol 1 137
> Superman Vol 1 141
> Superman Vol 1 152
> Superman Vol 1 154
> Superman Vol 1 217
> Superman Vol 1 257
> Superman Vol 1 286
> Superman Annual Vol 1 2
> Superman Annual Vol 1 5
> Superman Annual Vol 1 10
> Superman Family Vol 1 166
> Superman's Girlfriend, Lois Lane Vol 1 26
> Superman's Girlfriend, Lois Lane Vol 1 3
> Superman's Girlfriend, Lois Lane Vol 1 32
> Superman's Girlfriend, Lois Lane Vol 1 42
> Superman's Girlfriend, Lois Lane Vol 1 59
> Superman's Pal, Jimmy Olsen Vol 1 101
> Superman's Pal, Jimmy Olsen Vol 1 123
> Superman's Pal, Jimmy Olsen Vol 1 18
> Superman's Pal, Jimmy Olsen Vol 1 36
> World's Finest Vol 1 223
> World's Finest Vol 1 87
> World's Finest Vol 1 90

Answer (score 4):

1950-06    SUPERBOY #8     "When Superboy Was a SuperBABY"

1951-12    SUPERMAN #73    "The Mighty Mite!"

1953-07    SUPERBOY #26    "The Super-Tot From Smallville"

1956-02    ADVENTURE #221  "The Babe of Steel"

1956-12    ADVENTURE #231  "The Super-Feats of Superbaby"

1957-09    SUPERBOY #59    "The Super-Dreams of Superbaby"

1959-03    SUPERBOY #71    "The Stolen Stunts of Superbaby"

1959-06    SUPERBOY #73    "Superbaby in Scotland Yard"

1959-09    SUPERBOY #75    "Superboy's First Day at School"

1959-10    SUPERBOY #76    "The Super-Monkey From Krypton!"

1959-12    SUPERBOY #77    "The Grandson of Steel!"

1960-01    SUPERBOY #78    "The Origin of Superboy's Costume!"

1960-03    SUPERBOY #79    "Life on Krypton!"

1960-09    SUPERBOY #83    "The Invasion of Krypton!"

1961-03    SUPERBOY #87    "The Scarlet Jungle of Krypton!"

1961-07    SUPERBOY #90    "The Unwanted Super-Tot!"

1962-04    SUPERMAN #152   "Superbaby Captures the Pumpkin Gang"

1962-07    SUPERBOY #97    "The Super-Mischief of Superbaby!"

1962-08    ADVENTURE #299  "The Unwanted Superbaby!"

1963-01    SUPERBOY #102   "The Amazing Tots of Smallville!"

1963-06    SUPERBOY #105   "The Day Baby Lana Became "Super"!"

1963-07    SUPERBOY #106   "The Lair of Brainiac!"

1963-08    ADVENTURE #311  "Smallville's War Against Superbaby"

1963-10    ADVENTURE #313  "Father's Day on Planet Krypton"

1964-04    SUPERBOY #112   "Superbaby's Super-Pranks!"

1965-03    SUPERBOY #119   "Superbaby's First Time-Adventure!"

1965-04    SUPERBOY #120   "Superbaby's Golden Quest!"

1965-06    ACTION #325     "The Skyscraper Superman!"

1965-10    SUPERBOY #124   "Superbaby's First Fight!"

1966-06    SUPERBOY #130   "Superbaby's Search for a Pet!"

1966-10    SUPERBOY #133   "Superbaby's First Foster-Parents!"

1970-07    SUPERBOY #167   "The Day Superbaby Blew Up the World!"

1971-04    ACTION #399    "Superbaby's Lost World!"

1971-10    SUPERBOY #178   "Superbaby's First Friend!" (*there's a sequel to this story in SUPERMAN FAMILY #194 [1979-04])

1972-08    SUPERBOY #189   "The Runaway Superbaby!"

1973-02    SUPERBOY #192   "Superbaby's New Family!"

1973-07    SUPERBOY #196   "Big Race for a Mini-Hero!"

1980-11    NAO* SUPERBOY #11    "When You Wish Upon A TV..."

1981-02    NAO* SUPERBOY #14    "A Mix-Up In Magic" (with Zatara)

1981-07    NAO* SUPERBOY #19    "The Scrambled Egg-Hunt"

1981-12    NAO* SUPERBOY #24    "Little Green Men Who Weren't There"

*(The New Adventures of)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you please format this so it's possible to read it?  Use lines starting with "- " to create a bullet list, or put a blank line between each line that's supposed to be its own paragraph.  Please also make sure this is not simply a duplicate of the existing answer.